# Serial Comma During Change of Articles

Tags: articles, oxford-comma

Does a change of articles "reset" the item count when it comes to serial commas? For instance, if using the serial comma, does the statement "I am **the** author of the book *XYZ*, **a** presenter and teacher," require a comma after presenter, or does the change in article reset the number of items to two? I don't have a specific reason why it would, but in writing a similar sentence it struck me as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

In order to maintain parallel structure in your sentence, you would repeat the article, like this:

> I am the author of the book XYZ, a presenter, and a teacher.

Personally, I prefer the serial comma but it is considered a style choice. You could omit the comma there and the sentence would still be clear. You would still need the article for parallel structure though:

> I am the author of the book XYZ, a presenter and a teacher.